# Improving the binary search algorithm by modifying it so that it works faster when searching for a word in large number of words (word list)

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, search, binary-search

I want to search for a specific word from a sorted word list. my word list contains 100,000 words. 
  In order to improve the performance of binary search algorithm I want to modify it a bit. For example if I wanted to search for the word "apple" instead of applying the binary search algorithm on the whole word list. I will apply it to only the words that start with the letter 'a'. If I load the word list in array ,or vector, I know I would begin searching from index 0. The problem is I don't know what would be my last index for words that start with the letter 'a'.
  Any Ideas on how to know this last index?

Comment: One way would be to scan the list one time to populate last index (you can use binary search for this also). Since it is one time it will not affect your search performanc

Comment: Instead of using only the part that starts with the same letter, maybe just search the part with the same *two* first letters. Or even the one with the same first *three* letters. Or heck, just search the exact entry that represents your word and you're done instantly! See what I did there?

Comment: You need to keep an extra meta index about your data. Is it worth it? Time it I suppose. But your application would need to be super time critical for it to be worth putting the effort in for such  a small list of words `100,000`. ln(100,000) = 12 while ln(10,000) = 10 (so you save two comparisons but cost one extra lookup).

Comment: You need to do log2(n), not ln(n). Assuming even distribution of words with the first letter, and only searching with the first letter, you'll find it in 12 log2(3846), instead of 17 log2(100000). If you're doing millions of lookups, that could be significant.

Comment: Is this mandatory to use binary search? Maybe, you can use hash search, which is O(1)? You can use my double hashing example, which is "word counter " for the input file: https://olegh.ftp.sh/src/words.c.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you to implement [TRIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) instead of implementing binary search algorithm. For example: each letter will be node of [TRIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). The time complexity to build [TRIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is **O(W*L)**. **W** is number of word. **L** is average length of the word.   When you find the word from [TRIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) it takes **O(L)**.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider a simpler related idea: [interpolation search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search): it parallels how humans search through a telephone book for a particular name, the key value by which the book's entries are ordered.

> In each search step it calculates where in the remaining search space the sought item might be, based on the key values at the bounds of the search space and the value of the sought key, usually via a **linear interpolation**.
>
> The key value actually found at this estimated position is then compared to the key value being sought. If it is not equal, then depending on the comparison, the remaining search space is reduced to the part before or after the estimated position. This method will only work if calculations on the size of differences between key values are sensible.

Under the assumption of a uniform distribution of the data on the linear scale used for interpolation, the performance can be shown to be `O(log log n)`.

> Practical performance of interpolation search depends on whether the reduced number of probes is outweighed by the more complicated calculations needed for each probe. It can be useful for locating a record in a large sorted file on disk, where each probe involves a disk seek and is much slower than the interpolation arithmetic.

But the same is true for maintaining adjuntive indices / buckets.

Answer (score 1):

What the others are suggesting, if you generalize, is construct a [*trie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), and that's a good idea.
The advantage of a trie is you can use indexing for the first few letters, and that's faster than binary search.
Of course, you would unroll it.

Another idea you might consider is Bentley's unrolled binary search, which looks something like this:

```
i = 0;
if (word >= dict[i + (1<<16)]){i += (1<<16);}
if (word >= dict[i + (1<<15)]){i += (1<<15);}
....
if (word >= dict[i + (1<<1)]){i += (1<<1);}
if (word >= dict[i + (1<<0)]){i += (1<<0);}
```

where `word` is the word you're looking for, and `dict` is your sorted dictionary, and its size is `1<<17` strings.
It finds the dictionary entry you're looking for in 17 comparisons.
You probably have to pad out the dictionary to a power of two, by putting `"0x7f"` sentinel strings at the end.
An alternative is to make the indexing operation smarter, so any index over the size of the dictionary just gives you the sentinel string.

Keep in mind the comparisons are not expensive.
If two words differ in the first character, only the first character needs to be compared.
If they are the same in the first character, but differ in the second character, then only two characters need to be compared.
You don't compare the whole word until you're almost done.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the index of the first word that doesn't start with 'a'. Build a top-level index that gives the starting index of each character and use that to create the search ranges as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could segment the word list into 'bins', every word in a particular bin starts with the same letter. Based on the first letter of the searching word, pick the appropriate bin to search within. This would only require a one-time preprocessing of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `Trie ADT` to get good performance on search ops. Wherein, as soon as the user types 'X', all titles starting with 'X' are shown. This functionality would be very similar to what you see on Google, or YouTube, or Netflix. You can, obviously, put more/fewer constraints on the construction of the `Trie` to shape it however you please. Why Trie vs Array? Tries are faster. Read on to find out more.

Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) on Tries. An implementation of a [Trie ADT in Java](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/blob/master/leetcode/Trie.java). An implementation of a [T9 dictionary (like the good old days) in C](https://github.com/dray92/Programming-Questions/tree/master/T9%20Trie).